# problem with Solve/findroot and plotting when using NIntegrate

Tags: plotting, equation-solving

```
do[
eq11[q1_] := (2*(1 - Cos[2*Pi*q1]));
U = 1;
hq1[q1_] := ((eq11[q1])^2 + 2*U*n0*(eq11[q1]))^(1/2);
ha1[q1_] := (((eq11[q1]) + (U*n0))/hq1[q1]) - 1;
vv32[n0_?NumericQ] := n0 + 0.5*NIntegrate[ha1[q1], {q1, -0.5, 0.5}];
FindRoot[vv32[n0] == 1, {n0, 1}]; 
{n0,0,1,0.1}]
```

I am getting these errors:

> NIntegrate::inumri: "The integrand -1+(1.
>   +2(1-Cos[Times[<<3>>]]))/Sqrt[4.(1-Cos[<<1>>])+4(1+Times[<<2>>])^2]\n
>   has evaluated to Overflow, Indeterminate, or Infinity for all sampling
>   points in the region with boundaries {{0.,1.07577*10^-15}}."
>   NIntegrate::inumri: "The integrand -1+(1.
>   +2(1-Cos[Times[<<3>>]]))/Sqrt[4.(1-Cos[<<1>>])+4(1+Times[<<2>>])^2]\n
>   has evaluated to Overflow, Indeterminate, or Infinity for all sampling
>   points in the region with boundaries {{0.,1.07577*10^-15}}. "
>   FindRoot::nlnum: "The function value {0. +0.5\
>   NIntegrate[ha1[q1],{q1,-0.5,0.5}]}\n is not a list of numbers with
>   dimensions {1} at {n0} = {1.`}."

I want to plot between `n0` and `U` for values of `U` from `1-20`. The problem lies in using `FindRoot` to get the value of `n0`. Can anyone help me out?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Side issues: `do` or `Do`? Why `;` after `FindRoot`? Why not `Table`? Or skip it altogether?

Comment: Your integrand has a singularity at `q1 = 0` of the order `1/Abs[q1]` for `n0 != 0`, so the integral is divergent almost everywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code has a few syntax issues as noted in the comments. The following seems to work (if I understand correctly what you are trying to do)

Configure all functions to accept only numerical arguments:

```
Clear[eq11, hq1, ha1, vv32];
eq11[q1_?NumericQ] := (2*(1 - Cos[2*Pi*q1]));
hq1[q1_?NumericQ, U_?NumericQ, n0_?NumericQ] := ((eq11[q1])^2 + 2*U*n0*(eq11[q1]))^(1/2);
ha1[q1_?NumericQ, n0_?NumericQ, U_?NumericQ] := (((eq11[q1]) + (U*n0))/hq1[q1, U, n0]) - 1;
vv32[n0_?NumericQ, U_?NumericQ] := n0 + 0.5*NIntegrate[ha1[q1, n0, U], {q1, -0.5, 0.5}];
```

Define a function to provide $n_0$ as a function of $U$ (I used an initial search value of $0.1$):

```
Clear[n];
n[U_?NumericQ] := FindRoot[vv32[n0, U] == 1, {n0, .1}][[1, 2]];
```

Use `Plot` to obtain the graph (takes a few seconds). Note use of `Quiet` to suppress any messages from `FindRoot`:

```
Quiet@Plot[n[U], {U, 1, 20}, PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 0.5}}, 
  AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"U", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(n\), \(0\)]\)"}]
```

[image]

EDIT: As MichaelE2 commented, the integral seems to be non convergent, which is also reflected by significantly different output of `NIntegrate` with different values of `WorkingPrecision` option. Therefore, the answer only addresses the syntax issues of the OP code, and does NOT give a correct/reliable solution of the problem.

Comment: I don't think the integral converges; and the integrand is positive, so no principal value, either.  What do you think?

Comment: @MichaelE2 Indeed, did not bother to check this issue at all. Thanks for pointing this out.

Comment: Bro thanks a ton!

Comment: @Stelios What's the use of "[[1,2]]"in the line 
"Clear[n];
n[U_?NumericQ] := FindRoot[vv32[n0, U] == 1, {n0, .1}][[1, 2]];"

Comment: @jazz1001 `FindRoot` produces an output of the form `{n0->root}'. The [[1,2]] directive extracts only the number 'root'.

Comment: @jazz1001 An alternative to `[[1, 2]]` is `n0 /. FindRoot[vv32[n0, U] == 1, {n0, .1}]`, or perhaps better, `Block[{n0}, n0 /. FindRoot[vv32[n0, U] == 1, {n0, .1}]]`.

Comment: @Stelios Can you comment something on removing the singularity in the integral. I used Cauchy Principal values->True, is any reliable faster option beside this.