# Optimising the code for better performance, when using NIntegrate to solve a double/triple integral

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration, equation-solving

```
Clear[eq11, hq1, ha1, vv32];
eq11[q1_?NumericQ,q2_?NumericQ] := (2*(1 - Cos[2*Pi*q1] + Cos[2*Pi*q2]));
hq1[q1_?NumericQ, q2_?NumericQ, U_?NumericQ,n0_?NumericQ] := 
  ((eq11[q1, q2])^2 + 2*U*n0(eq11[q1, q2]))^(1/2);
ha1[q1_?NumericQ, q2_?NumericQ, n0_?NumericQ,U_?NumericQ] := 
  (((eq11[q1, q2]) + (U*n0))/hq1[q1, q2, U, n0]) - 1;
vv32[n0_?NumericQ, U_?NumericQ] := 
  n0 + 0.5*NIntegrate[ha1[q1, q2, n0, U], {q1, -0.5, 0.5}, {q2, -0.5, 0.5}];

Clear[n];
n[U_?NumericQ] := FindRoot[vv32[n0, U] == 0.5, {n0, .1}][[1, 2]];

Quiet@Plot[n[U], {U, 1, 20}, PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 1}},AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
  AxesLabel -> {"U", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(n\), \(0\)]\)"}]
```

When I am solving for 1-d it runs in about 5 secs, but for 2-d (the one above) it takes a lot of time and still running. Can anyone help me out with the problem?

For 1-d case, this the code:

```
Clear[eq11, hq1, ha1, vv32];
eq11[q1_?NumericQ] := (2*(1 - Cos[2*Pi*q1]));
hq1[q1_?NumericQ, U_?NumericQ, n0_?NumericQ] := ((eq11[q1])^2 + 2*U*n0 (eq11[q1]))^(1/2);
ha1[q1_?NumericQ, n0_?NumericQ, U_?NumericQ] := (((eq11[q1]) + (U*n0))/hq1[q1, U, n0]) - 1;
vv32[n0_?NumericQ, U_?NumericQ] := n0 + 0.5*NIntegrate[ha1[q1, n0, U], {q1, -0.5, 0.5}];

Clear[n];
n[U_?NumericQ] := FindRoot[vv32[n0, U] == 1, {n0, .1}][[1, 2]];


Quiet@Plot[n[U], {U, 1, 20}, PlotRange -> {{0, 20}, {0, 0.5}}, 
AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
AxesLabel -> {"U", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(n\), \(0\)]\)"}]
```

Comment: What code do you use for the 1-d case?

Comment: @bbgodfrey I edited the question with the 1-d case's code

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/72946/problem-with-solve-findroot-and-plotting-when-using-nintegrate

Answer (score 1):

2_D Integration is slow (and incorrect), because the integrand, `ha1` is singular in parts of the integration domain for `n0 = 0.1` (and elsewhere), as can be seen in the plot below for `U = 5`.  Perhaps, your equations or domain of integration need to be corrected.  In general, using `Quiet` is unwise, when debugging a code.

[image]

(The plot is ragged at the singularity, because too few `PlotPoints` were used in creating it.)

**Addendum**

`ha1` is singular where `hq1 = 0`.  The `ContourPlot` below of `hq1^2` indicates that this is true on four semicircles.  Note that `hq1^2 < 0` in the darkest region.  Thus, `hq1` and `ha1` are complex there.

[image: hq1 squared]

Comment: As far as I know the Integral/ 'ha1'is correct. May be integration domain need to be changed. Can you suggest any way to remove the singularity?

Comment: Changing the domain to exclude the singularity is, of course, easy to do, but the choice for doing so should be based on the actual mathematical problem you are trying to solve.  I notice that `hq1` involves `Sqrt`, which has a branch cut.  Is it possible that a different branch than the normal one should be chosen?

Comment: yeah, we can choose the normal branch cut.

Comment: I used Cauchy Principal value-> true to take care of the singularity. Can you please comment on removing the singularities with any other faster option.

Comment: I do not believe that `PrincipalValue -> True` does take care of the singularities in this case.

Comment: Can you suggest any other method for this case?

Comment: Without knowing the physical problem you are attempting to solve, I can only suggest that you cannot integrate over the regions containing the singularities.  But, I would guess that the issues are deeper than this.